# "On shown" event when manually use bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-events, twitter-bootstrap-2

Problem appears when I try to show modal for the first time. Modal is shown but the `shown` event is fired when I drag the modal or click on the close button (I see the alert). I am using `Bootstrap 2.3.2` with `Firefox 26.0`.

```
$("#modalXML").modal({ show: false });
$(document).on("click", "#idStart", function(){
    $("#modalXML").modal('show');
});

$("#modalXML").on("shown", function(){
   alert('juhu');
});

<a target="_blank" data-toggle="modal" href="#" class="clsXML" id="idStart" >Button</a>


<div id="modalXML" class="modal hide fade in">
    <div class="modal-header" id="">  
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>  
        <h3>XML file</h3>  
    </div>  
    <div class="modal-body" id="idModalBodyXML">
        <textarea rows="10" cols="150" id="xmlTextArea">
        </textarea> 
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">  
        <button name="button" value="" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</button>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the `show` event instead?

Comment: Can you provide HTML markup associated to this JS script?

Comment: Please provide your HTML code. It is useful for other people to help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found where is a problem. Instead of

```
     <div id="modalXML" class="modal hide fade in">
```

I set (without "in")

```
   <div id="modalXML" class="modal hide fade">
```

Now, "on shown" event works.

Thank you all.

Comment: It is not matter of `in` class. It works great even with the in class [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9cHhC/)

Comment: @user3165879 In my case it doesn't work when I have "in" class, and I don't know why. Your code also don't work on my page, but works on fiddle. Maybe some other js have influence.

Answer (score 1):

It works here in this example:

The following line of code `$("#modalXML").modal({ show: false });` was not hiding your modal during my experimentation.  `$("#modalXML").hide();` worked well though.. Take a look at the example hopefully it will help you.

```
$("#myModal").hide();
    $(document).on("click", "#launch", function(){
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
    });
    $("#myModal").on("shown", function(){
       alert('juhu');
    });
```

Example:

http://www.bootply.com/109094

Comment: I already have hide class on my html tag for modal. I tried to initialise modal with $("#modalXML").modal({ show: false });, because after one click event and call for $("#modalXML").modal('show'); it works every next click. Same thing is when I put line with "show: false" or omit.

Comment: @gormit I guess I don't have a clear understanding of your question.  Can you create a `bootply` that demonstrates the issue you are having?